# Foundation 6 - jQuery - scrollTop not working for mobile

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

in Foundation 6, jQuery scrollTop not working for mobile:

```
var hpSecondSection = $('#hp-section-2'),
    fixedTopBar     = $('#header-top-bar');

    $('.scroll-down-bar').click(function() {

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: hpSecondSection.offset().top + fixedTopBar.innerHeight()
        }, 400);

    });
```

This issue is provided by `.off-canvas-wrapper`, that makes mobile menu panel to work and has `overflow-x: hidden`

I can't find a solution about this.. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://blog.jonathanargentiero.com/jquery-scrolltop-not-working-on-mobile-devices-iphone-ipad-android-phones/, mobiles don't know what HTML and body is. You should use solution provided in the link to achieve desired effect like so:

`if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|Android)/)) {

            window.scrollTo(200,100) // first value for left offset, second value for top offset
}else{
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: 100,
                scrollLeft: 200
            }, 800, function(){
                $('html,body').clearQueue();
            });
}`

Comment: You're right about the selector, but it's not the problem described. If you try in foundation 6, when the mobile panel init, you'll find the issue I wrote above. Any selector does not make sroll to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can still determine where the scroll is (in percentage from 0 = top to 100% = bottom) using `.scrollY` and using `outerHeight()` (which gets recalculated if e.g. the browser bar is hidden) rather than `height()`:

```
let scrollPercent = 100.0*window.scrollY / ($(document).height() - $(window).outerHeight());
```

Crude, but it works for me.